# Bigquery querying dirtectly over csv files in Google Storage

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to ask you for guidance with a technical query on GCP.

is it possible in bigquery to directly read and query a CSV file from storage without the need to load a table?
For example, if I have 2 csv in the paths gs: //mybucket/file1.csv and gs: //mybucket/file2.csv, could I make a query directly on the files? Something like 'Select * from [myproject.mybucket.file2.csv]'

My goal is to be able to query information, on demand, from a set of (large) csv files, with from-to dates of the files. My goal is not to have the data loaded if it will not be used and to consult data only when necessary.

If this is not possible, what recommendation do you give me to not have all the data permanently loaded?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done.  What you need to do is define an external table, which allows you to query the data in cloud storage without ingesting it.  See this for more information: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage

If your CSV files in cloud storage are also organized in a format compatible with a hive partitioning layout, you can also use that to help reduce scanned data or leverage it as an additional pseudocolumn of the table.  If not, note the guidance around `_FILE_NAME` which can also be of use if the filename of the CSV is relevant to your queries.